# PHP foreach of table result

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I want to separate these images using explode or somthing else.

```
IMAGES = http://i.imgur.com/2L1nGRP.png&http://i.imgur.com/GnsB51Q.png
```

I want to transform it in an array.

Comment: Why don't you simply [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) them by the common separator `&`? That's assuming that there are no query strings in the image URLs themselves.

Comment: First: I am not really sure what is your question here -> [How to ask](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) - read it. Misty guess -> what about `explode('&', $string)`?

Comment: I wouldn't use an `&` as a separator for URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the string using '&' as the delimeter.

`$images = array_explode('&', $query[1]->Image);`

This will give you an array of the image urls from your input string.